# Why does Trisha Elric have tomatoes?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

In many episodes where Trisha (the boys’ mother) is seen, she is carrying, tending to, or harvesting tomatoes.

[image]
(*Trisha in her tomato field; she is carrying tomatoes in her apron.*)

Why does she have these tomatoes? Does she home-grow all of their food, or is this just a hobby of hers?

Comment: It was not stated in the anime itself. She probably just liked to tend tomatoes because she has tomatoes and that's why she liked tomatoes. Tomatoes are healthy and I'm not making sense anymore. XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Village of Resembool is a sheep-farming town in Amestris and is well known because of this

[Village of Resembool](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Resembool)

If you have watched the anime when Ed and Al go back home there are a lot of farms

[image]

So my guess is that she harvested her own vegetables for their food and maybe for trading.

Comment: Did she grow anything else? I don't remember seeing anything else, but it makes me curious.

Comment: No, in the anime and manga she only appears harvesting tomatoes... but in the episodes where Ed and Al are little you can see many vegetables and fruits in their house.

Answer (score -1):

This is my own guessing, but it may be the truth.

I read some researchers about tomatoes and their nutritional value, and it found out that their lycopene value is very high, and considered to be helping with cancer and more disease.

It might be pure guess, but it may suggest that the authors of FMA wanted to let us the readers/watchers know that Trisha is already in deep disease, and so that's the reason she raises them.

https://www.nfcr.org/blog/tasty-tomatoes-anti-cancer-attributes-healthy-recipe/